# how can I override sinatra's get method?

Tags: logging, sinatra, metaprogramming

I want to be able to override the get method in Sinatra, but normal ruby overrides don't work, here is my code:

```
 require 'sinatra/base'
 class WebApp < Sinatra::Base
   def get
     format =  "url #{url} AT: #{Time.now}"
     puts format
     super
   end
   get "/" do
     puts "hi"
   end 
   run!
 end
```

I am able to visit "/" , it will print "hi",  but it won't print the format from log_request, how can I override the get method properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get` method *adds a route handler* to the Sinatra app; it's only used for building the app during startup. When the app is up and running, the incoming HTTP requests no longer call `get`, they call the internally stored proc instead. (And the same goes for `post` etc.)

Based on your description, it looks like you want a `before` handler - its contents will be run for every incoming HTTP request before the actual route handlers are run.

So try replacing the `def get ... end` block in your code with the following:

```
before do
  puts "URL: #{request.url}  AT: #{Time.now}"
end
```

Then again, if you just want to log the incoming requests to the console, the easiest way is to say `enable :logging` inside your class definition. See more detail here: http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html

Comment: thank you, I looked at the docs before, but didn't see a before filter, I see it now.